# How to schedule a batch class every third Sunday of a month at 12:00 lunchtime Central US Time zone

Tags: schedulebatch

How to schedule a batch class every third Sunday of a month at 12:00 lunchtime - Central US Time zone - in an anonymous window?

`System.schedule('Batchex', '0 24 19 ? * *' , new Batchex());`

I used the above code to run a batch class every day at 7:24 PM.

Comment: [The Apex Scheduler documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm) would be the place for you to start your research. Be aware that the CRON expression won't be able to make adjustments for Daylight Saving Time.

Comment: You could use following website and learn more on how to create the CRON expression
https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following: **0 24 19 ? * 1#3**

0(Seconds) 24(Minutes) 19(Hours) ?(Day of Month) *(Month) 1#3(Day of Week)

You can check this [here](https://www.forcetalks.com/blog/using-cron-expression-in-salesforce/) for more info.